# Instantiate chaincode from Java SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to instantiate a chaincode from a Fabric Java SDK Client using code from this 
[example](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk)

When i am trying to add imports inside chaincode ie
`github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/ci`

I am getting error from the peer

```
2018-05-30 17:03:24.813 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 038 [mychannel][6326fbfe] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "chaincode/input/src/github.com/ify/ify.go:40:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid" in any of:
/opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid (from $GOROOT)
/chaincode/input/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid (from $GOPATH)
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid
```

where should i install the packages inside peer in order to be visible from the go builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put everything in vendor, as stated in the [coding guidelines](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/Style-guides/go-style.html): Hyperledger Fabric uses Go Vendoring for package management.
In this way you can import external libraries in the chaincode.

Comment: I have added all the dependency using govendor into the $GOPATH. However, I am receiving a similar error as above. Any suggestions?

Comment: if I understood correctly you are adding in the $GOPATH of your machine. You don't have to add the dependency in the $GOPATH of your machine. You are running on a docker container (the chaincode container), so the $GOPATH referred by the message is the $GOPATH in the chaincode container. Try to put the vendor folder inside the chaincode folder of your project ([as in fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/chaincode)). Me I did like that in my [chaincode](https://github.com/pavva91/trustreputationledger), hope I was clear enough